# xor definition (this sentence is to make the title acceptable)

Tags: c#, c++, xor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ‘^’ do in c# (Enums)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234776/what-does-do-in-c-enums)

This may be a noobish question but...nowhere have I seen what Xor means in C++ or C#.  I think it might mean and/or and if it does, I'm smart cause that's a blind guess =D.  I use C# now but I'm pretty sure xor means the same thing.  The problem is - I don't know what xor means.  I know that xor is represented by a ^ though.  I also would like to know what ^^ means.

Comment: Duplicate of many questions, including [What does '^' do in c# (Enums)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234776/what-does-do-in-c-enums) = and [
Is the ^ operator really the XOR operator in C#?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508153/is-the-operator-really-the-xor-operator-in-c).

Comment: You should change your title to something like "What does XOR (^) mean in C++/C#?" or something like that. (though, I think XOR means the same thing in all languages) :D

Answer (score 6):

Exclusive or between two bits means that the result is 1 if one and only one bit is 1.

The truth table is:

```
   | 0 | 1
---+---+---
 0 | 0 | 1
 1 | 1 | 0
```

When you talk about xoring a larger value, it's just taking each bit one at a time, so:

```
    1111 0000
xor 1010 1010
    ---- ----
  = 0101 1010
```

For what it's worth, a full list of binary operations:

- `and`, 1 only if both its inputs are 1, else 0.
- `or`, 0 only if both its inputs are 0, else 1.
- `xor`, 1 only if one (not both) of its inputs is 1, else 0.
- `not`, 1 only if its input is 0, else 1.

And the truth tables:

```
and| 0 | 1      or| 0 | 1     xor| 0 | 1     not| 0 | 1
---+---+---    ---+---+---    ---+---+---    ---+---+---
 0 | 0 | 0      0 | 0 | 1      0 | 0 | 1        | 1 | 0 
 1 | 0 | 1      1 | 1 | 1      1 | 1 | 0
```

Answer (score 2):

A google search for "define: xor" will point you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor, the fountain of all knowledge. Reading this will give you an insight as to what exclusive-or (XOR) means :)

Goodluck

[edit]
And just to clarify, xor does not mean and/or, sorry. And the definition of xor is programming language independent.

Comment: There is no `^^`, since it can't be made to short-circuit, and `!=` and `^` both work as non-short-circuiting boolean XOR.

Comment: ...unless your language doesn't have strict booleans.

Answer (score 1):

XOR stands for 'eXclusive OR'.
Exclusive Or operation result is true, only if one of the arguments is true, not both.

Having 1 as the value of true, and 0 as the value of false, bitwise operation gives 1 when only one of the bits at corresponding position is 1.